# The pandas 'read_html' function is creating duplicate values in other columns, why is this happening?

Tags: python, html, pandas

Randomly, the `read_html` function in the Python library pandas started incorrectly reading data from an html file output from SAP.

I am using a python script to convert an html file output from SAP to JSON in order to use the data in PowerBI. This script is running in an Azure function, and has been working perfectly for the past 2 months. Randomly last Wednesday, it started putting the customer name in both the correct column and the column next to it, shifting all the other cells over. The html file is made up of several tables with a fixed row-count, and this only happens to one of the tables, usually the 17th. Here are some screenshots of what I'm talking about:

The first image is the output file from SAP, showing the correct data in the correct columns.

[image: SAP Output]

The next image shows the output in PowerBI. The data in the JSON is the same, it is not a problem with the import.

[image: Imported into PowerBI]

The code that is being run is:

```py
with open(file_path,'r',encoding='utf-8') as file:
    contents = file.read()
list_of_dataframes = pd.read_html(contents)
list_of_dataframes.pop(0)
df = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes)
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df.drop(0,inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df.fillna('null', inplace=True)
df.to_json(file_name + ".json", orient='records')
```

I have removed things in the code like the actual file path, but everything else is what is being run. This problem is happening both in Azure and on my personal machine. I have no idea why this is happening, file from SAP did not change, neither pandas nor Python updated on my machine or Azure, and it went from working perfectly to having errors every time.

Comment: Scripts and batches may stay the same, but some changes in data may have started the mess. I'd suggest you comparing two file contents: before and now.

Comment: That was my second thought after accidental updates, but it is happening to multiple different reports.  I guess it might be an update to SAP, so I will check on that.